# Flask's send_from_directory from Azure Container

Tags: flask, azure-web-app-service

I've seen the similar questions, but this is specific for Azure container.

There's a Storage Account(SA) and container(das_container)

The HTML page has a button where the user should be able to download the blob(`ja_file.txt`) from the `das_container` with click on the button

```
<input type="submit" value="dw_button" name="dw_button" />
```

Flask part:

```
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def get_file(path):
    return send_from_directory('/<directory-on-azure-container>',filename='ja_file.txt', as_attachment=True)


@app.route('/index', methods=['POST'])
def yes_download():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = request.form.to_dict()
        if 'dw_button' in x:
            get_file(path)
```

The `BlockBlobService` is setup.

The question is how to set the path to Azure container in the `get_file()` method? The premise of the question is that's the problem.

Comment: Which paltform you use ?

Comment: @JasonPan Windows, `<directory-on-azure-container>` maybe is the local directory

Comment: `send_from_directory` should not be possible, in windows web app. It should not be possible, in windows web app. If you are using linux, it may be achieved through `path mappings`.

Comment: send_from_directory is used on the webserver server, and it uses the server path. If you want to download files, it is recommended to create a class similar to HttpClient in C# in the code to download, and then download through stream.

Comment: If you agree with my statement, I will send out my answers below.

Comment: @JasonPan, OK, I agree, send the answer

Comment: I have send my answer, you are very kind. ^-^ You also can update your solutions in your post to help more forum users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send_from_directory` is used to read the path where the project is deployed on the webserver.

It is recommended to download the file or create an `HttpClient`, and then process the file through `Http request`, which can return to the form of `Stream`. Of course, you can also find a `package` for use.